# Convert time to formatted string; result is truncated

Tags: c, time.h

I need to convert a `time_t` variable into string of format **DD/MM/YYYY/HH:mm**. I made the following function.

```
int time_to_str(time_t value, char *string)
{
    struct tm *timeinfo;
    time(&value);
    timeinfo = localtime(&value);

    strftime(string, sizeof(string), "%d/%m/%Y/%H:%M", timeinfo);
}
```

Testing the function with the following:

```
time_t variable = time(NULL);
char buffer[100];

time_to_str(variable, buffer);

printf("%s", buffer);
```

I get the following output and I don't see the problem... Any ideas?

```
07/10/
```

Comment: `sizeof(string)` is always 4 or 8 on any modern PC (depending on whether you compile for 32 or 64 bit), so that's obviously wrong

Comment: Yes, you'll need to pass that as an additional function parameter. The function doesn't return any `int` value as required, either.

Comment: Ahhh right, actually wanted to use a macro here, no idea how I messed this, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `strftime` should be the size of the buffer to write to, i.e. 100 in this case. `sizeof(string)` results in the size of a *pointer to char*, which is usually 4 or 8. Hence, `strftime` only writes several characters to the `string` buffer.

For more information, see the documentation for [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime).